# getting unfortunately error when trying to use httpclient and printing integer

Tags: android

I can not understand what logcat say, because I'm not really old for android development.
Here is the [logcat](http://pastebin.com/dsR6PGqu). Codes are below..

```
public class Json extends Activity {

    HttpClient client;
    TextView tvStatus;

    final static String url = "http://localhost/index.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.json);

        tvStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        try {
            int data = this.users();
            String Data = String.valueOf(data);
            tvStatus.setText(Data);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public int users() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
    {
        StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(url);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(URL.toString());
        HttpResponse r = client.execute(get);

        int status = r.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        return status;  
    }
}
```

Just trying to get status and appending into tvStatus. What may the problem and solution be?

Comment: Please don't make people follow links.  Please edit your question and paste the logcat in.

Comment: @Simon I cannot paste a lot of codes. Rule of stackoverflow

Comment: http://blog.vogella.com/2012/02/22/android-strictmode-networkonmainthreadexception/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` which means you are trying to execute a network operation in UI Thread, which is not allowed. You will have to execute your code in a separate thread. Either use `AsyncTask` or create a `new Thread()` and make the call from there.